# Provider's token was read as null

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, dart, angular-dart

I have a Dart application that is based on the tour of heroes tutorial. With respect to the root injector it's more or less identical. Nevertheless, webdev build is producing the error shown in detail below.

I am using the Dart SDK 2.3.2 on Windows 10. As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555733/upgrading-to-dart2-angular5-error-importing-template-dart) I tried running pub cache clean. Also tried deleting the entire generated folder, then running pub cache clean, but still get same error. Note that this exact same application builds fine in a Linux Docker container. Also, whether as a cause or result of these errors I cannot tell, but main.template.dart is not being generated.

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:http/browser_client.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:web_front_end/app_component.template.dart' as ng;
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';

import 'dart:html';

import 'main.template.dart' as self;

@GenerateInjector([
  ClassProvider(Client, useClass: BrowserClient),
  routerProvidersHash,
])
final InjectorFactory injector = self.injector$Injector;

void main() {
  runApp(ng.AppComponentNgFactory, createInjector: injector);
}
```

Here are the errors generated when I run webdev build.

```
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 1.7s
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 1ms
[INFO] Serving `web` on http://127.0.0.1:8080
[SEVERE]angular:angular on web/main.dart: line 15, column 23 of asset:web_front_end/web/main.dart: Unable to parse @GenerateInjector. A provider's token (ClassProvider ((super) = Provider (deps = Null (null); multi = bool (false); token = Null (null); useClass = Type (BrowserClient); useExisting = Null (null); useFactory = Null (null); useValue = String ('__noValueProvided__')))) was read as "null". This is either invalid configuration or you have analysis errors
   ╷
15 │ final InjectorFactory injector = self.injector$Injector;
   │                       ^^^^^^^^
   ╵
[SEVERE]build_web_compilers:entrypoint on web/main.dart: Unable to find modules for some sources, this is usually the result of either a
bad import, a missing dependency in a package (or possibly a dev_dependency
needs to move to a real dependency), or a build failure (if importing a
generated file).

Please check the following imports:

`import 'main.template.dart' as self;` from web_front_end|web/main.dart at 9:1

[INFO] Running build completed, took 12.7s
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 314ms
[SEVERE] Failed after 13.0s
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. In my case, it was happening because of a conflict in import
2 packages containing the same ClassName.

```
import 'dart:html'; // Contain the class Location
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart'; // Also contain the class Location
```

So the issue can be resolved by adding an alias on one of these packages:

```
import 'dart:html' as dhtml;
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';
```